# How to bring back round window corners on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization, appearance

I like the look of Windows XP, and Windows 7, and like the round corners of the windows of the apps.  Windows 10 seems to take a step to remove them and make it 90 degree corners.

Are there ways to bring back the round corners on Windows 10?

Comment: In short no, Microsoft decides what they look like.

Comment: I guess it is more like saying Microsoft doesn't provide a way to customize the look, and currently there may be no 3rd party tool to do that either

Comment: Full Windows customization pretty much ended after Windows XP.

Answer (score 3):

## The answer would be using the "hidden" aero-lite theme.

Quoting from Sergey Tkachenko at the link provided:

> Similar to Windows 8, the brand new Windows 10 comes with a secret
> hidden Aero Lite theme, which can be enabled with just a simple text
> file. It changes the appearance of windows, the taskbar and also the
> new Start menu.

#### Instructions at [http://winaero.com](http://winaero.com/blog/enable-the-hidden-aero-lite-theme-in-windows-10/)

---

---

#### Here is a (not very informative) discussion about the removal on [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/why-the-glass-like-transparent-windows-borders-and/d68dd84f-f211-4f4e-8504-d4fe2c44024a).

Comment: theme was indeed applied, but windows are still completely rectangular. Too bad.. the rounded windows were a nice touch. Maybe MS will bring them back.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a bit of a budget then there is [Windowblinds](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/) for custom themes.  However programs that don't have a standard title bar like Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome can be a bit tricky to get working with it.  If all your programs have standard title bars then it is compatible with Windows 10.